# how can I find the mime type of a file-url on the web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mime-types, mime

Is there a way to check if the file I'm loading from a URL is an image or a video.

How do I differentiate between an image-type & video-type and parse them accordingly on my webpage.

i am using next.js and want to create nft previews on my web app.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different methods using **`fetch()`**.

The first method gets the MIME type from the “*Content-Type*” header and seems a lot faster, and the second from a blob.

```js
var Img = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/SmallFullColourGIF.gif';

function GetMimeTypeTest(URL){
   fetch(URL).then(response=>{T1.innerHTML=response.headers.get('Content-Type');}).catch(error=>{alert(error);});

   fetch(URL).then(function(response){return response.blob();}).then(function(blob){T2.innerHTML=blob.type;});
}
```

Run the test...

```
GetMimeTypeTest(Img);
```

HTML containers to get the results...

```html
<div id="T1"></div>
<div id="T2"></div>
```

Tip: To get the file size use the header "*Content-Length*" or *blob.size*